# Standalone library module is not recognized by Android Studio if I add build flavors to it

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have an Android project that is dependent on a standalone android library module (`Commons`). The project's main module (`app`) has two build flavors: `development` and `production`. I need to add such flavors to library module (`Commons`). Problem is that when I add these two flavors, module `app` does not recognize module `Commons` java code and complains that "Add dependency on module 'Commons'". I already have this dependency:

In `settings.gradle`:

```
include ':app'
include ':Commons'
project(':Commons').projectDir = new File('../Library/Commons')
```

In `app` module's `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    //...
    compile project(':Commons')
}
```

In `Commons` module's `build.gradle':

```
productFlavors {
    development {
        //...
    }
    Production {
        //...
    }
}
```

If I remove these two flavors, project compiles without any error. What is wrong? Is it a bug or did I do something wrong?

Comment: "has two build flavors: development and production" -- why? You already have `debug` and `release` build types. Product flavors are for different distribution options (e.g., Play Store code vs. Amazon AppStore code for in-app purchasing). Are you planning on shipping `development` to customers? With respect to the problem, while it should not be needed, have you tried duplicating the line as `developmentCompile` and `productionCompile`, to see if that gives you any clues?

Comment: Also, if you have the `dependencies` closure before the `android` closure, try inverting that, to have the `dependencies` closure appear after the `android` closure. I have seen some other flavor-related dependency problems reported here on SO get cleared up by ensuring that the flavors are defined before you try using dependencies. This *specific* case doesn't ring a bell, though, so this may not help.

Comment: I know that this naming is not good! I want to separate network addresses while developing and in production with this these flavors and I wanna know that can I have a module with two flavors? If yes how?

Comment: I did re-order build.gradle as you told and the problem is still there :(

Comment: "I want to separate network addresses while developing and in production" -- to me, that sounds like the role of the `debug` and `release` build types. And I just realized that I misunderstood your question -- AFAIK, library modules do not support product flavors at the present time.

Comment: Thank you. Another question: How can I separate network addresses while developing and in production with build types?

Comment: I would use `buildConfigField` to add values to `BuildConfig` that represent relevant addresses. `buildConfigField "String", "SERVER_URL", '"http://test.this-is-so-fake.com"'` and the like. See https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/Gradle/HelloBuildConfig/build.gradle Then, your Java code refers to `BuildConfig.SERVER_URL` for things like Web service calls.

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm!

Comment: @CommonsWare Not so sure about the support for flavorsin library. According to doc http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system, with the plugin 0.9.0, DSL for Library Projects is now the same as for application projects.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti: Yeah, but I think there are problems with it. I may be wrong and it's gotten better in recent months, but I know for certain the times that I tried it, I ran into roadblocks that were big enough for me to just not bother with 'em.